# Create a JAR file in eclipse dynamically from the code

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I am currently working on a ***TESTING*** a game project. Below are the details about my project.

This is my first Maven Project and I really have very less idea on it's working methodology.Please help me!

1] **GameProject** - Is a Maven Project in Eclipse. The main goals of this project is to create a game player (also called *bot*) for a First Person Shooter game. When you run this Java Application, it will run the game, with a new player, whose actions will be determined by the code I wrote up in this project.

It has lot of java files, and one main class. There is a class called **PlayerInfo.Java**, which contains the code to decide, what the player should do while playing the game. It is like the brain of the player. Let's say it has around 40 variables, which decides the behavior of the Player.

*Example* - One of the variable in the class may be like **Player_HEALTH_Level = 50**. This means that Player should have atleast 50% of the health to be able to fight with other players. If it's less than this, then He/she should find a health Pack and increase the value. Similarly I have few other 39 parameters.

2] **Testing Project** - This too is a maven Project. Which is designed to test my Player(bot) performance in the game. Such as, how many times he wins the match, number of weapons he collects, etc.

The way this project is designed that, it requires the path for the JAR file of the **GameProject** as a input in the Main Method. Then, It runs the bot/player for the given JAR and prints out the results of the game in a separate file.

Example - 
In the Main Method I specify something like this

String playerJAR_Path = "C:\Users\Player\Netbeans\GameProject-one-SNAPSHOT-jar.jar"

Note:- The above is the path for GameProject JAR folder. Basically, I just build the GameProject as "Maven Install" and it will create a JAR for me. Then use the path address on the second Project.

Hope this gives you some idea about my project structure.

Issue

The real issue is I have to basically run my GameProject around 500 times and capture the results. I am using Genetic Algorithms to evolve the Player Parameters and improve them over the time.

Currently, I can have a for Loop in my TestingProject, to loop 500 Iterations and it takes cares of executing the GameProject 500 times for me.

In order to apply Genetic Algorithms, After the end of EACH iteration, I have modify the parameters in the Player/bot Behavior (Specifically in file **PlayerInfo.Java**). Something like, I may change the value for **Player_HEALTH_Level=48** for the iteration 2 run, then to 56 on the third run and so on.

In oreder to do this, I need to acheive the follwing in my Testing Project inside my FOR Loop.

Perhaps may be like this

```
*For int i=1 to 500 do ;
String playerJAR_Path = "C:\\Users\\Player\\Netbeans\\GameProject-one-SNAPSHOT-jar.jar";
Run the Testing();
Modify the parameters in PlayerInfo.Java (Inside GameProject)
Change the values of 40 Variables in that class.
Build the GameProject Project so that, it creates a UPDATED JAR File
End FOR;*
```

I am really confused, as in how to build the first project automatically, and also how to change the values of the class variables.

Can any one please help me on giving some suggestions on how to achieve the same. I don't mind in what way to do this. Just be able to AUTOMATE This whole testing Process.

**Other details:**
1. System - Windows 7, Intel Xeon 12 Core Processor, 24GB RAM, 3 TB Flash Drive. 
2. For each iteration on the For-Loop, it produces a million record (As in the console window of the Eclipse will contain a Million lines for each iteration in for loop). I also need to know, how to write this to a file, instead of flooding console. 
When I tested this initially, Eclipse hang up with Out of Heap Memory Error. Then I have increased all RAM values to 2GB in the eclipse INI file. This somehow managed not to crash my eclipse with memory errors.

*EDIT* - Adding code to Question.

```
public class PlayerInfo {
public int minDistanceToFollowEnemy = 200; // This is in UT Units. If Bot sees an enemy over this distance
    // He/she tries to follow him and attack.

public int probabilityToFollowEnemy = 50; // Distance between the bot and Enemy will be calculated in real time.
    //If the distance is lower, chasing priority is Higher.

public int probabilityOfFlagHolderReturn = 50; // If the Bot holds the Enemy flag, what's the probability that he/she
        //Runs to home base directly without being distracted to collect items, fight with enemies?

public int probabilityOfGettingEnemyFlag = 10; // If bot does not carries the enemy flag, it's probability to hunt for enemy flag.


public double maxDistanceToGetHealthPack = 1000 ; // If Bot finds a health pack within this distance && It needs a Health pack
           // Then It searches one and grabs it.

public int minHealthLevel = 30; // Min Health level before bot starts looking for Health Pack

public int probabilityToGetHealthPack=80; // Probability that Bot will Pick one health pack if it sees on its path/view.

public int probabilityToSelectItem = 8 ; //Based on the current Bot's view, what's the probability that it will select to choose the item.

}
```

Main Class PlayerBot.java IN GameProject

public static void main(String args[]) throws PogamutException {

```
AddNativeBot addbot = new AddNativeBot();
//addbot.addNativeBots(4);

// starts 2 or 4 CTFBots at once
// note that this is the most easy way to get a bunch of bots running at the same time
new UT2004BotRunner<UT2004Bot, UT2004BotParameters>(CTFBot.class, "PlayerInfo").setMain(true)
.startAgents(
        new CTFBotParams().setBotSkin("HumanMaleA.MercMaleC").setBotType(0).setSkillLevel(5).setTeam(0).setAgentId(new AgentId("Attacker 1"))
        //,new CTFBotParams().setBotSkin("HumanFemaleA.MercFemaleA").setSkillLevel(5).setTeam(0).setAgentId(new AgentId("Attacker 2"))
        //,new CTFBotParams().setBotSkin("HumanMaleA.MercMaleA")    .setSkillLevel(5).setTeam(0).setAgentId(new AgentId("Attacker 3"))              
        //,new CTFBotParams().setBotSkin("HumanFemaleA.MercFemaleB").setSkillLevel(5).setTeam(0).setAgentId(new AgentId("Attacker 4"))
        //,new CTFBotParams().setBotSkin("HumanFemaleA.MercFemaleB").setSkillLevel(5).setTeam(1).setAgentId(new AgentId("Attacker 5"))
        //,new CTFBotParams().setBotSkin("HumanFemaleA.MercFemaleB").setSkillLevel(5).setTeam(1).setAgentId(new AgentId("Attacker 6"))
        );
```

}

//Project 2

```
public static String[] getArgs_CTF_2v2v1() {
        return new String[] {
                "-y", // MATCH TYPE
                "CTF", // CAPTURE THE FALG
                // GENERIC CONFIG
                "-u",
                "C:\\UT",
                "-h", // human-like-log
                "-r",
                "./results",
                "-n",
                "Test-CTF-2v2v1", // MATCH NAME
                "-s",
                "CTFServer",                
                // CUSTOM BOTS CONFIG
                "-a",
                "C:\\Users\\Project\\Downloads\\CTFbot\\target\\mavenproject1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.one-jar.jar;C:\\Users\\Project\\Downloads\\CTFbot\\target\\mavenproject1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.one-jar.jar",
                "-b",
                "CTFBot1;CTFBot2",
                "-l",
                "1;2",
                "-k",
                "HumanFemaleA.NightFemaleA;HumanFemaleA.NightFemaleA",
                "-i",
                "0;1",
                // NATIVE BOTS CONFIG
                "-c", // NATIVE BOT COUNT
                "2",
                "-d", // NATIVE BOT NAME
                "Native1;Native2",
                "-e", // NATIVE BOT SKILL
                "5;6",
                "-g", // NATIVE BOT TEAMS
                "0;1",
                // HUMANS CONFIG
                "-x",
                "1", // HUMAN COUNT
                "-z",
                "1",
                // CAPTURE THE FLAG SPECIFIC CONFIG
                "-m",
                "CTF-LostFaith",
                "-f",
                "1", // SCORE LIMIT
                "-t",
                "5", // TIME LIMIT
            };
    }
```

//Main Class

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSAPException {
        // -----------
        // FOR TESTING
        // -----------
        //args = getArgs_DM_2v2v1();        
        //args = getArgs_TDM_2v2v1();
        args = getArgs_CTF_2v2v1();     

        // --------------
        // IMPLEMENTATION
        // --------------

        initJSAP();

        header();

        readConfig(args);

        sanityChecks();

        switch (matchType) {
        case DM:
            executeDeathMatch();
            break;
        case TDM:
            executeTeamDeathMatch();
            break;
        case CTF:
            executeCaptureTheFlag();
            break;
        case DD:
            executeDoubleDomination();
            break;
        default:
            fail("Unsupported match type specified " + matchTypeName + " recognized as " + matchType.shortName + "[" + matchType.name + "].");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: write output to file --> use logging for logging output and use FileWriter for other output. For the rest of your problems: search for tutorials - any helpful answer will be too long for Stackoverflow

Comment: I am very new to Maven and all. Any helpful tips on what topic/tutorials to study would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You think you need to re-compile/deploy the application each time its configuration parameters change?

Comment: Yes, I want to re-create the JAR with new class variables each time.

Answer (score 1):

Holy wall of text.

Ok, couple of things. Just because Maven created a jar for you, doesn't mean you have to use the jar. You could call the class directly.

So your testing would instantiate the class, instead of trying to run the class from the command line.

Second. You don't have to modify the internal state of the variables directly. My advice is for you to save the changes to a file and have your Player read the file. For the next iteration you modify the file and run the Player again.

Let me know if you have specific questions and I'll improve the answer.

Comment: I am sorry for long text. Just wanted to give as detailed information as possible. The issue is, I did not write code for the Testing Project. It has lot's of Java Files, and dependencies JAR. It just takes the JAR Path of the FIRST Project as input Parameter. Just looking for way to build the JAR for the first automatically. Writing the parameter to a file and reading them at can be done. But what about JAR Building?

Comment: No worries. :) Just that long descriptions (as short ones) scare people who will try to answer your question.

Comment: Please help me Alexandre Santos.

Comment: Sure man, but I can't make bricks without clay. Make this: post a simple code. One class with attributes and a tester class and I can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Code is huge. Just added it for you. Please have a look at it.